# Preparing a Resume/CV with latex?

Tags: resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)
>
> **See also:**
> [What are the benefits of writing resumes in TeX/LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11955/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-resumes-in-tex-latex)

Being a beginner, I just finished typing my first report in latex and I realized its great feel for presentation. Then the idea sprang up, that I can use latex to prepare my resume/CV too.

I googled and found not very interesting sites which guided me with samples or templates.

It would be great if some can guide me with some good tools, URLs, templates, samples so that I can prepare my CV/Resume to its best presentation.

Thanks!

P.S: Resume/CV which I can use for applying to universities.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11955/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-resumes-in-tex-latex

I am finding answers in the above link. A moderator can remove the question if required.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Here too..

Comment: Since the answers to those two questions seem to be enough for you, we'll close this one as a duplicate of one of those so that others can easily find them as well.