# Creating a resume template? A beginner's education

Tags: templates, resume

I've began learning LaTeX for the expressive purpose of eventually creating a resume template of my own. A business school friend of mine showed a very professionally-looking resume he created from a workshop, and I would like to turn it into a LaTeX template. I know there are already many existing resume templates, but I would like to create my own.

I also know that there are many tutorials and guides for LaTeX, but I would like to know if there are any that can lead me towards creating templates, specifically something in resume/cv form. I know that it will be a long and arduous task to learn how to create templates, much less a template for a stylized resume, but I would like to make that my goal for learning the language.

Would it be simpler to just modify or tweak a preexisting template?

Comment: Joseph Wright wrote a series of blog posts about how he wrote his CV in LaTeX, that might be interesting: http://www.texdev.net/tag/curriculum-vitae/

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11955/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-resumes-in-tex-latex). I've found the easiest method is to start with a standard class (`article` or `report`), and then tweak it using `geometry`, `titlesec`, `enumitem` and `minipages`

Comment: I suggest you browse a bit [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org). There are lots of templates to choose from. By taking a look at the code you can get a glimpse under the hood.