# Using LaTeX to create a resume in PDF

Tags: pdftex, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)
>   [What are the benefits of writing resumes in TeX/LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11955/what-are-the-benefits-of-writing-resumes-in-tex-latex)

I am a LaTeX noob and I am considering it for revamping my resume.  I decided to shift away from MS Word as I dislike using MSFT products and would like something like HTML with hyperlinks but want to create one single file with embedded images.  I will also have a hierarchy tree structure (simiar to a filesystem tree).

My questions are:

1. Is LaTeX a good tool to produce a complex single document that matches the above description in format
2. I read [here](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/GF/bibliog/latex/LaTeXtoPDF.html) that it is tricky to convert DVI -> PDF.  Is that still the case?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: duplicate? [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80)

Comment: Besides that 1. has been similarly asked, 2. is a completely different question and should be separate, if you would like to ask this. It would just be good to be more concrete, as vague questions are hard to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, LaTeX is a good tool to produce such documents. Especially the [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) class is very nice for resumes. Adding URLs is not a problem in LaTeX.
However, there is a certain learning curve involved and it might take you a little while to get your first complex document in the form you want.

Nowadays there many editor and tools like `latexmk` that will help you a lot with compiling your document with LaTeX. Also, with `pdflatex` (and other TeX compilers) you can now produce a PDF directly without going over DVI etc. and this is IMHO also the recommended way to go.

Answer (score 2):

1.:
LaTeX is a very good tool for creating complex documents. You have to get used to it. But when you are, you will never want thomething other. Very many scientifical docuemnts are writeen in LaTeX. You can add links with the packages hyperref and url.

2.:
By now it is very simple. You can just use pdflatex, and you will directly get PDF output.